# trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, 15.04

I am trying to install KDE on Ubuntu 15.04. I ran sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop and got this output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-desktop-applets : Breaks: kde-telepathy-legacy-presence-applet but 1.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libksgrd5 : Depends: libkf5sysguard5-data (= 4:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libksignalplotter5 : Depends: libkf5sysguard5 (= 4:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libkf5sysguard5-data (= 4:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libktpotr9 : Breaks: libktpotrprivate8 (< 15.03.80) but 0.9.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libprocesscore5 : Depends: libkf5sysguard5-data (= 4:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libprocessui5 : Depends: libkf5sysguard5-data (= 4:5.2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and got this output:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.19.0-15 linux-headers-3.19.0-15-generic
  linux-headers-3.19.0-21 linux-headers-3.19.0-21-generic
  linux-image-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-15-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-21-generic
  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-21-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
602 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/121 kB of archives.
After this operation, 712 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 371396 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Would someone take a look at those and give me any pointers?

Comment: Remove the `account-plugin-google` package.